# Installing Visual F# in Express with Professional already installed

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional, and I'm trying to get an installation of [VS Express for Desktop 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787) with F# support. I installed VS Express and the [Visual F# Out Of Band Release 3.1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41654) as indicated on [fsharp.org](http://fsharp.org/use/windows/), but after both completed, nothing F# shows up in VS Express. No F# Interactive window is available and no templates for creating an F# project. Is this because of a conflict with Visual Studio 2013 Professional? Is there a way to get F# support in VS Express with VS Professional installed side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply uninstalled and reinstalled Visual F# and that seemed to fix the problem. I have no idea what caused it in the first place. :S

Comment: Did you install the F# package before or after you installed VS Express?  The F# installer only deploys templates, etc if it detects you have the relevant VS SKU installed.  So if VS Express was installed after, then you need to repair/reinstall F# so it detects the new SKU and drops the appropriate bits.

Comment: That might have been it (and would make sense given how I resolved it), but I thought I had installed things in the correct order.